# How do you change the default folder icon for all folders?

Tags: windows-8.1

Where is the variable stored for the default folder icon in the registry? Is there a setting in control panel that will allow me to do so? Is there a simple script that goes through all folders and changes the icon? etc. 
I can't seem to find a straight answer anywhere.

Comment: Hi, I found something for Windows 7. It is likely that it could be the same for Win 8.1 as well. Follow http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/23825-folder-icon-change-windows-7-default-folder-icon.html

Answer (score 1):

Due thanks to Prassana's Comment Link (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/23825-folder-icon-change-windows-7-default-folder-icon.html). What you can do to change the default folder Icons is to add these to the registry(This is in Batch(Command Prompt)) You need Administrator Permission for this to work: %input% is the Full Path of the Icon:

```
REG ADD "\\%COMPUTERNAME%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6532NODE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\EXPLORER\SHELLICONS" /f
REG ADD "\\%COMPUTERNAME%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SHELL ICONS" /f
REG ADD "\\%COMPUTERNAME%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6532NODE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\EXPLORER\SHELL ICONS" /v 3 /t REG_SZ /d %input% /f
REG ADD "\\%COMPUTERNAME%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\EXPLORER\SHELL ICONS" /v 3 /t REG_SZ /d %input% /f
```

And on the next restart your default folder icon will be changed! (Keep in mind this does not change the folder icons that are already modified.)

EDIT: Here is a nifty batch(.bat) script I created that solves this problem in a more user friendly way:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO ------------Folder Icon Changer( Windows 8.1 )------------
ECHO.
ECHO Started!
IF NOT [%1]==[] (SET input=%1) ELSE (SET /p input=" Enter Full Path of Icon(.ico) file: ")
REG ADD   "\\%COMPUTERNAME%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6532NODE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\EXPLORER\SHELL ICONS" /f
REG ADD "\\%COMPUTERNAME%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\EXPLORER\SHELL ICONS" /f
REG ADD "\\%COMPUTERNAME%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6532NODE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\EXPLORER\SHELL ICONS" /v 3 /t REG_SZ /d %input% /f
REG ADD "\\%COMPUTERNAME%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\EXPLORER\SHELL ICONS" /v 3 /t REG_SZ /d %input% /f
ECHO Finished! ERRORLEVEL: %ERRORLEVEL%
CLS
ECHO For changes to take affect, you must restart your computer.
SET /p answer= Would you like to do this now(Yes/No)?: 
IF [%answer%]==[Yes] (SHUTDOWN -R)
IF [%answer%]==[No] (ECHO Restart will occur later.)
PAUSE
```

Comment: How about supply the batch script instead of linking to a private Dropbox account that might or might not exist tommorow